Sorting a JSON array by an arbitrary order using jq
Given this JSON data in the file data.json:
[
  { "id": 1, "entityType": "cat" },
  { "id": 2, "entityType": "dog" },
  { "id": 3, "entityType": "bird" },
  { "id": 4, "entityType": "cat" }
]

How would return an array sorted by some non-alphabetic arbitrary order (e.g dogs, birds and then cats)?
I've tried various permutations along the lines of:
jq --argjson order '["dog", "bird", "cat"]' '. | sort_by( index($order[], .entityType) )' data.json

but without any joy.

It's easier (and faster) to use an object for the order:
jq --argjson order '{"dog":0, "bird":1, "cat":2}' \
    '. | sort_by($order[.entityType])'

But if you insist:
jq --argjson order '["dog", "bird", "cat"]' \
    '. | sort_by(.entityType as $type | ($order | index($type)))'


Thanks for the suggestions - they both work.
I had got close but hadn't identified that I needed to introduce the variable $type.
I'm curious to know why your second suggestion works but
jq --argjson order '["dog", "bird", "cat"]' '. | sort_by($order | index(.entityType))'
throws an error (jq: error (at data.json:6): Cannot index array with string "entityType" )
Any thoughts as to why $type is needed rather than being optional?

Because using | .entityType makes it relative to the current context, which is $order. The original context is lost; to preserve it, you need to store it in a variable.

If you want to keep your order argument an array, sort by turning it into an implicit boolean array of matches. Note that false will be ordered before true, so use != to "mismatch" the items.
jq --argjson order '["dog", "bird", "cat"]' 'sort_by(.entityType != $order[])'

[
  {
    "id": 2,
    "entityType": "dog"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "entityType": "bird"
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "entityType": "cat"
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "entityType": "cat"
  }
]

Alternatively, provide the order as single arguments using the --args option and the $ARGS.positional array:
jq 'sort_by(.entityType != $ARGS.positional[])' data.json --args dog bird cat


cool use of $ARGS.positional

If the order is defined by an array, then for efficiency it would typically be worthwhile converting the array to a dictionary along the lines suggested by @choroba:
< input.json jq --argjson order '["dog", "bird", "cat"]' '
   INDEX( $order | to_entries[]; .value ) as $dict
   | sort_by( $dict[.entityType] )
'

